# Does Youtube count views from facebook?

Tags: youtube

I am not sure if this is the place for the question but i am sure someone here has experience with it.

Last month i have uploaded several videos to Youtube and linked them on facebook page.

First one has 54 views counted in Youtube. On facebook it says 14 shares, 1.1k views.

Another video had Instagram boost, around 10k likes, 46k reach, 500 clicks, and on Youtube total of 1.1k views.

When testing with different browsers i do not see views number increasing when looking embed video on Facebook.

Answer (score 2):

What counts as a view on Facebook are way different that what counts on YouTube. Facebook is famous for its [defense on three second views](http://marketingland.com/facebook-defends-its-3-second-video-view-standard-137823). This is in contrast to YouTubes complex algorithm that determines a legitimate view or not. This is why you see such a large difference in views between the two platforms.